# Jenkins groovy - how to separate url path and filename

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-groovy

$url = "http://bus00cyb.ind.testserver.com:8080/job/IOTF-7.4.x-BITBUCKET-REPO/51/artifact/output.txt"

I have a Jenkins job parameter which has takes 'url' value as an user input. I want to separate the param as below:

$url_path = "http://bus00cyb.ind.testserver.com:8080/job/IOTF-7.4.x-BITBUCKET-REPO/51/artifact"
$filename = "output.txt"

How to do this using jenkins pipeline groovy script? Pls suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if I'm understanding your question correctly but in groovy you will have something like this:

```
url = "http://bus00cyb.ind.testserver.com:8080/job/IOTF-7.4.x-BITBUCKET-REPO/51/artifact/output.txt"
urlsplitted = url.split('/')
filename = urlsplitted[urlsplitted.length-1]
shorturl = url-filename
println(shorturl)
println(filename)
```

Comment: In my usecase, i have an url entered in the job parameter; something like "http://bus00cyb.ind.testserver.com:8080/job/IOTF-7.4.x-BITBUCKET-REPO/51/artifact/output.txt". I need to split the base url path and filename separately and use that for my automation purpose. Need to know how to do this in jenkins groovy script?

Comment: I've updated the answer after your comment

Answer (score 0):

```
U can use regexp (.*)\/(\w*\..*)$
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.*)\/(\w*\..*)$");
Matcher m = p.matcher("http://bus00cyb.ind.testserver.com:8080/job/IOTF-7.4.x-BITBUCKET-REPO/51/artifact/output.txt");
If (m.find()){
    filename= m.group(2)
    url=m.group(1)
}
```